# What Turbo Tyre On CX Bike

Tags: cyclocross, turbo-trainer

I have a CX bike that i would like to put on a turbo trainer. The bike is Boardman CX Comp.

The question i have is what turbo training tire could i put on my wheels Mavic XM319?

My current tires are Schwalbe Tyrago Kevlar Guard 700 x 37c what tires could replace these?

What tire options do i have and am i limited to what turbo trainer i can use?

I have yet to try any tire and i have tried to google to get an answer but dont fully understand the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can use any 700c trainer tire like the [Continental Hometrainer](http://www.conti-online.com/www/bicycle_de_en/themes/race/hometrainer_en.html) , [Vittoria Zaffiro Pro Home Trainer](http://www.vittoria.com/tire/zaffiro-pro-home-trainer/), [Kurt Kinetic's Trainer tire](https://kurtkinetic.com/products/trainer-tires/), etc. Most come in 700x23, but some come in larger sizes (700x32 for example for the Continental Hometrainer). You can also just use a regular tire on a trainer, but the tire will wear out faster due to the additional heat versus the road. On a road, you [don't want to go too far from a particular range of widths](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width) due to either flats or handling issues, but since you're bolted into a trainer, theres not a problem in using a smaller 700c tire on the wheel.

As for trainers you can use, pretty much any trainer supports 700c, but as always, check the specifications for the one you're going to buy.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the turbo trainer for the size wheels they support. 
There are turbo trainer specific tires but you can train on a regular tire. 
Just google "bicycle tire for turbo trainer". 
You have 700 rim = 622 iso.
At CX races I see riders warming up on turbo trainers with the knobby tires they are going to race with.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to fit an older part-worn rear tyre if you're going to keep the bike in the trainer all winter.  You can buy a new good tyre come spring.

If your trainer doesn't spin the front wheel like rollers do, consider using up the front tyre by install it on the rear wheel and shout yourself a pair of new ones when it warms up.